# Related to entire functions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying some problems from complex variables with applications written by  ponnusamy and silverman and is struck on this question - 
If two entire functions agree on a  segment of real axis, must they agree on whole complex plane? 
I don't know how to approach. 
Please help.

Comment: Look at the function defined by their difference. Apply the uniqueness property of power series.

Comment: Assuming this segment has an accumulation point, yes. This is the identity theorem